# Android Service Class - OnCreate called only once

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm starting a BroadCast Receiver when net Connectivity Changes in Android. The `BroadCast Receiver` Starts a Service which handles a Async task to fetch data from server. The problem is little weird, when i test in my device the Service `OnCreate` method is run for first time "Hurray!" but when i disconnect the network and again try to connect. The BroadCast is Read but not the Service. Am I missing something here? or Is this a bug? or should there be any Intent Actions when I start my Service? Please Help me.

Comment: I could also notice that OnStart method works fine and starts every time it is called but not OnCreate! can some one tell me why this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **onCreate** method in service runs only once till the entire life of service. However, calls to **onStartCommand** method can be made multiple times by calling *startService*. If your service is *destroyed* and then run again, the **onCreate** will be called again.

This is what [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) document tells:

`onCreate()`

`The system calls this method when the service is first created, to perform one-time setup procedures (before it calls either onStartCommand() or onBind()). If the service is already running, this method is not called.`

Comment: Only 1 time in the onCreate ? I debug my app, and call everytime

Comment: Now I tried with  my debug and I don't see increment of internet ... I'm confused...

Comment: @delive as long as your service is running **onCreate** will not be called. It is only called when starting service for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The **onCreate** method of the service will be called first time you start the service only.

Unless you stop the service by **stopService** or **stopSelf** methods, the service will be running and the **onCreate** will not be called again.

But **onStartCommand** will be called each time you call **startService**

To Know More : [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Is there a way to make the onCreate to be called even when I finish my service with stopService/stopSelf?